# pull без merge с локальными коммитами

Tags: git, git-pull

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при выполнение pull не делался merge-commit с локальными коммитами? т.е. нужно чтобы не было коммита "Merge branch 'master' of git://github.com/repo into local-branch", а вместо этого, локальные коммиты находились бы на самом верху.

Как это выглядит в обычной ситуации с pull:

```
commit f70cfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Merge: 88acfcc8 f70cfcc
Author: User <user@example.loc>
Date:   Sun May 13 15:00:00 2018 +0300
Merge branch 'master' of git://github.com/repo into local-branch

commit 88acfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: Other User <user@example.loc>
Date:   Sun May 13 12:00:00 2018 +0300
Local commit 2

commit с6acfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: Other User <other_user@example.com>
Date:   Sun May 13 10:00:00 2018 +0300
Commit 2 from remote branch

commit 78acfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: Other User <other_user@example.com>
Date:   Sun May 13 09:00:00 2018 +0300
Commit 1 from remote branch

commit d54cfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: User <user@example.loc>
Date:   Sun May 13 05:00:00 2018 +0300
Local commit 1
```

Нужно:

```
commit 88acfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: User <user@example.loc>
Date:   Sun May 13 12:00:00 2018 +0300
Local commit 2

commit d54cfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: User <user@example.loc>
Date:   Sun May 13 05:00:00 2018 +0300
Local commit 1

commit с6acfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: Other User <other_user@example.com>
Date:   Sun May 13 10:00:00 2018 +0300
Commit 2 from remote branch

commit 78acfcc8ef025dfe03a98eff675d56c1132eec74
Author: Other User <other_user@example.com>
Date:   Sun May 13 09:00:00 2018 +0300
Commit 1 from remote branch
```

Comment: `git pull --rebase`

Comment: @PetSerAl Спасибо! То что нужно. Если хотите, можете добавить ответ - отмечу как решение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. `pull` состоит из двух этапов - получение указателей из удаленного репозитория (`fetch`) и слияние изменений локальной и удаленной веток.
Слияние возможно двумя способами (см. [документацию](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) - `merge` и `rebase`.

Достичь того, чтобы при `pull` использовался `rebase`, а не `merge` можно разными способами. Например:

- Добавить опцию `--rebase` к команде pull
- Настроить такое поведение по умолчанию `git config --global pull.rebase true`